# Is there a way to change the y axis of the calc.ece function when plotting?

Tags: function, plot, yaxis

I am trying to plot the `calc.ece` function and have been successful with just the basic `plot` function. However, I need to be able to zoom in to show the observed and calibrated lines better. Such as in this example here

```
LR.same = c(4135, 4135, 4135, 4135, 4135, 4135)
LR.different = c(0.00334, 0.00334, 0.00334, 0.00334, 0.00334)
ece.1 = calc.ece(LR.same, LR.different)
plot(ece.1)
```

I cannot use the `ylim` as I get this error `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  argument "x" is missing, with no default`. I am unsure what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still cannot change the y-axis in R, but if you just `unlist()` the data and export you get the data. I then put the data into excel and added a column of log10 odds which is calculated by log10(prior/(1-prior)). Then I just created a scatter plot of this making the log10 odds the x-axis. That seemed to work.